# Adjusting the overall width of a table

Tags: tables, geometry

My table extends past the margin of my `.pdf` file. I already set the margin using the `geometry` package. How will I be able to adjust the width of my table so that it will be within the specified margins?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The width of a table necessarily depends on its content ;-)

Comment: Exactly what @ChristianHupfer said. If you are using the `l`, `r`, or `c` column types perhaps you can use the `p{<width>}` type for some of the wider columns. Or perhaps scale the table as per [How to fit a wide table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71419/how-to-fit-a-wide-table), or reduce inter-column spacing  But a specific solution will depend on you actual use case so best to put together a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that represents your problem table.

Comment: I managed to fix the width of my table using p{<width>} type. My problem now is that all my text is aligned to the left. I need most of my text to be center aligned. I tried using \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{content} for each cell, but it disregarded the parameters I set in the p{<width>}. How will I be able to center align my text while keeping the specified parameters?

Comment: @Reg so please show us your MWE to see how are you working with that table and can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in a comment:

> I managed to fix the width of my table using `p{<width>}` type. My problem now is that all my text is aligned to the left. I need most of my text to be center aligned.

To define a column type that center-sets its contents *and* takes a width specifier, you could add the following code to your preamble

```
\usepackage{array}     % for \newcolumntype macro
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for \Centering macro
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Then, use the `C` column type instead the `p` column type for those columns whose contents should be center-set. (By the way, the `p` column type *fully justifies* its contents; your comment would appear to suggest that it left-aligns its contents.)

Aside: The advantage of using `\Centering` instead of `\centering` is that hyphenation of words will be allowed. If you want to suppress hyphenation within the `C` columns, use the `\centering` directive instead.